# jquery ajax and google chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home_tab").click(function(){
        $("#content").hide(); 
        $("#content").load("php/media_body.php");
        $("#content").show("slow");
    }
});
```

I'm using the jQuery Ajax library to pull some HTML content from a PHP file on my server. The above code works beautifully in IE and Firefox but, for the love of me, I cannot get it to work in Chrome. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks,

-Johnny

Comment: What does the error console say?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern may work better for an asynchronous request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#home_tab").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").hide().load("php/media_body.php",function(){
      $(this).show("slow"); 
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url:'php/media_body.php', 
 data: "data=data",
 success: function(answer){eval(answer);} 
});
```

Safari and Chrome have client side security feature to prevent phishing. This way is more "secure".

And use an $('#whereToAppend').append() wrapping all the HTML of your file.